# Objective C @interface ... <NameOfThis> {...}

Tags: objective-c

The question is in the title but I don't know if it's clear. I have to do a report and I want to know how to call that part of the `@interface` declaration in a .h file :

```
@interface NameOfTheObject ; TYPE < ??? > { instance variables }
```

I don't how to name the `???`. I hope it's more understandable and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a protocol. What your class does when declared like this is called *adopting* or *conforming to* a protocol.